# How do I use LINQ to select a collection of inner XML nodes?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-xml

I have the following xml.  Given, a `UID`, `Manufacturer Name` and `Image Layout`, I want to pull out all possible sizes that exist in the xml.

```
<Rules>
  <UniqueID UID="123413">
    <Manufacturer Name="XYZ Company">
      <Image Layout="Portrait">
        <Size rows="512" cols="512" price="x" />
        <Size rows="1024" cols="1024" price="y" />
      </Image>
    </Manufacturer>
  </UniqueID>
</Rules>
```

The way i do it right now is:

```
XElement rules = XElement.Parse(xmlDoc.OuterXml);

var uids = rules.Elements("UniqueID")
                .Where(x=> (string)x.Attribute("UID")=="123413")
                .ToList();

foreach(var uid in uids)
{
    var manufacturers = uid.Elements(("UniqueID")
                           .Where(x=> (string)x.Attribute("Name")=="XYZ Company")
                           .ToList();
}
```

and so on until I have a collection of the possible sizes.

So I am using 3 foreach loops. Is there a better way acheive this with probably one line of code, using LINQ?

Comment: Any reason why you're not using semicolons at the end of each line?

Comment: @Rafe: Probably because OP originally had the code posted in with tick marks.  So they were probably all separate lines of code, not a continuous code block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a little bit of a mouthful, but you can use XPathSelectElements:

```
 var sizes = rules.XPathSelectElements("//UniqueId[@UID = '123413']/Manufacturer[@Name = 'XYZ Company']//Size");
```

Obviously, you could use string formatting to dynamically insert values for @UID and @Name.

Make sure to include `System.Xml.XPath`.

Comment: Does this have substantial performance benefit than stacking lINQ statements?

Comment: I don't think so.  It's main virtue is conciseness.  XPath is a very expressive language, and often makes for easier-to-read code than straight-up linq methods.

Answer (score 1):

I like James's XPath approach. Here is what it might look like if you just keep stacking LINQ.

```
var sizes = xmlDoc.Elements("Rules")
    .Elements("UniqueID")
    .Where(e => e.Attribute("UID").Value=="123413")
    .Elements("Manufacturer")
    .Where(e => e.Attribute("Name").Value=="XYZ Company")
    .Elements("Image")
    .Where(e => e.Attribute("Layout").Value=="Portrait")
    .Elements("Size");
```

`sizes` ends up being IEnumerable (2 items)

```
<Size rows="512" cols="512" price="x" />
<Size rows="1024" cols="1024" price="y" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this(used XPath):

```
String xmlString = @"<Rules> <UniqueID UID=""123413""> <Manufacturer Name=""XYZ Company""> <Image Layout=""Portrait""> <Size rows=""512"" cols=""512"" price=""x"" /> <Size rows=""1024"" cols=""1024"" price=""y"" /> </Image> </Manufacturer> </UniqueID> </Rules>";
XElement element = XElement.Parse(xmlString);

var uids = element.XPathSelectElements("//UniqueID[@UID=123413]/Manufacturer[@Name='XYZ Company']/Image[@Layout='Portrait']/Size")
          .Select(a=> new {rows=a.Attribute("rows").Value, cols=a.Attribute("cols").Value})
        .ToList();  
foreach(var uid in uids) 
{     
    Console.WriteLine(uid.rows + " - " + uid.cols);
}
```